Power Automate: Automate Adding New Clients to Microsoft Bookings from Microsoft Forms Submission Trigger
I'm trying to set up a workflow that automatically adds new clients to Microsoft Bookings based on submissions from a Microsoft Forms form. Here's a breakdown of what I'm aiming to achieve:

Trigger: A client fills out a Microsoft Forms form.
Action: Check if this client already exists in Microsoft Bookings.
If New Client: Add the client to Microsoft Bookings.

I attempted to build this using Power Automate, but I couldn’t find an action under the Microsoft Bookings connector to add a new client directly.

What I’ve Tried:

Set up the trigger for the form submission in Power Automate.
Explored available actions in the Microsoft Bookings connector but didn’t find a way to create a new client directly.

Additional Details:

I’m using the built-in connectors in Power Automate, and I’m open to any workaround solutions if a direct action doesn’t exist.
I also created some diagrams that illustrate the desired workflow, which I’m happy to share for clarification if needed.

Question:
Is there a way to add clients to Microsoft Bookings programmatically when they don’t exist already? If there’s no direct action, could someone suggest an alternative approach to achieve this?
Any insights or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help!


My answer is contentious because it doesn’t actually provide you with the instructions on how to use it but, if there’s no direct action, then you need to use the MS Graph API ...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/bookingcustomer?view=graph-rest-1.0#methods
There are numerous tutorials and resources online for how to authenticate and make the relevant calls to such things.
